# Log the filename tee writes to

Tags: linux, shell, tee

Let's say I am in my home directory /home/xyz/

Now, I execute `uname -a | tee test0.txt` and a minute later I execute `ls | tee test1.txt`.

After every execution of tee, I want it to be logged into log.txt in the same directory.

log.txt should contain the the time of execution of tee and the filename it wrote to.

It would be nice, if the commands used are in the same "line" of the tee command (e.g. 1 command which does everything, including the log)

Comment: You could replace `tee` by a script (say `mytee`) that does that and calls `tee` internally, but I doubt it is possible with `tee` itself. It is just a usecase `tee` wasnt built for

Answer (score 0):

Command `xtee`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") ": $*" >> log.txt
exec tee "$@"
```

Usage:

```
uname -a | xtee test0.txt
ls | xtee test1.txt
```